# Creating a multiline blockquote with quill

Tags: quill

I'm not sure where to start with this. The documentation is a little opaque, and I haven't really been able to find good examples.

Basically I want to be able to have a multiline blockquote. The way blockquote works now in quill is that each line break is itself another blockquote.

```
<blockquote>Author name</blockquote>
<blockquote>Another paragraph</blockquote>
```

However I want to be able to nest blocks like p and other blockquotes inside

```
<blockquote>
  <em><small>Author name</small></em>
  <p>Body of text</p>
  <blockquote>
    <em><small>Author name</small></em>
    <p>another body of text</p>
  </blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

Any pointers or good examples of how this could be accomplished would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue. have you found any solution?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? If it's purely styling, most things can be achieved in CSS, especially using the [`+` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).